# How to return existing reactElement from render

Tags: reactjs

From the error description, I understand that render can return classes and strings but not an already created object. However, is there a workaround?

```
const Hello = React.createElement("div",{},"Hello");

var MyComp = React.createClass({
render:function(){
return(<Hello/>)
}
})
```

**ERROR in return:**
 Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object

Answer (score 0):

The workaround is that you need to create a div inside a Reacts component and only then can you render it.

> We pass some methods in a JavaScript object to React.createClass() to create a new React component. The most important of these methods is called render which returns a tree of React components that will eventually render to HTML.

[DOC](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html)

```js
var Hello = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      React.createElement('div', {},
        "Hello, world! "
      )
    );
  }
});

var MyComp = React.createClass({
render:function(){
return(<Hello />)
}
})

ReactDOM.render(<MyComp />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react-dom.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```